# How to create a text file through PHP and download the text file in user computer

Tags: php

I have tried several option but the text file saves in root server correctly but I want user to download the text file and save in his computer. I have got the download result by using

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
```

It downloads the whole script in user computer instead of only "text" result `$textToWrite`, which I want to download. Code I have tried are as follows:

```
$textToWrite = "$cdacode"."$cda_name"."$subofcode"."$subofname"."$name_payee"."$acno2"."$ifsc"."$micr_cd"."$act_type"."$pay_amt"."00"."DV NO"."$pmt_ref_no"."$paybydate"."$vendcode"."$vend_add"."$bill_num"."$billdate"."$narration"."$emailid"."$mob_num"."$addn_field";

$file= "$cmpno.txt" ;
$current .= "$textToWrite";

file_put_contents($file, $current);

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
```

Comment: Code has to be in the php code tag so it can be correctely displayed. It's also easier to read.

Comment: If you want to send the contents of `$textToWrite` as a file to the user, you don't need to write it to a file and then read it again - just `echo $textToWrite` at the end.

Comment: Although... I am wondering if you have just missed off the `<?php` at the start of this script!

Comment: @halfer echo $textToWrite will  show text contents in the browser it self. I just want to download as "content-disposition;attachament;"

Comment: Just put the `echo` after your `header()` statement, and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$textToWrite = "$cdacode"."$cda_name"."$subofcode"."$subofname"."$name_payee"."$acno2"."$ifsc"."$micr_cd"."$act_type"."$pay_amt"."00"."DV NO"."$pmt_ref_no"."$paybydate"."$vendcode"."$vend_add"."$bill_num"."$billdate"."$narration"."$emailid"."$mob_num"."$addn_field";

$file= "$cmpno.txt" ;
$current .= "$textToWrite";

file_put_contents($file, $current);

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
readfile($file);
```

Comment: I tried but result is same, the whole script of the page downloaded as text format, I just want result to be downloaded as text.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments: as far as I can see, there are two issues with the code:

- You have no opening PHP tag, and I wonder if you are just serving this script as text
- You're pointlessly writing a file and then doing nothing with it

Try this code:

```
<?php

// @todo This rather needs tidying up
$textToWrite = "$cdacode"."$cda_name"."$subofcode"."$subofname".
    "$name_payee"."$acno2"."$ifsc"."$micr_cd"."$act_type".
    "$pay_amt"."00"."DV NO"."$pmt_ref_no"."$paybydate"."$vendcode".
    "$vend_add"."$bill_num"."$billdate"."$narration".
    "$emailid"."$mob_num"."$addn_field";
$file= "$cmpno.txt";

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
echo $textToWrite;
```

As per my comments the string is in a bit of a mess - try this first to see if we're on the right track, and if this broadly works, I'll show you how to tidy it up.

Comment: as I mentioned in my original question file_put_contents($file, $current); is doing fine, it is saving text file in root folder in the server, but it is not open to user, i want user to download the text file in his computer. further echo $textToWrite shows text results in browser , that is also I donot want.

Comment: Yes, your approach will work. However, as I mentioned in the comments, writing to a file just to read it again is pointless - just echo it. You need to work out why the headers are failing. Do you have any whitespace before the PHP opening tag? Also, try swapping the `Content-type` and `Content-disposition` headers around, so the second one comes first.

Comment: result coming always in this format as edited above pl see your post above,

Comment: sorry could not upload image of text file created

Comment: Hi @MH_007. Please don't edit my post to illustrate the problem - I've rejected that pending edit. It is best to use the original post for this purpose. If it does not allow you to embed an image, just use imgur.com or similar, and add a link.